# login form not submitting after adding new fields to table .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I added 1 new field to my table, added the field to Model DTO and Model ViewModel cs,  but Login form submit seems to be not working post that. 
There is no error showing, login page simply refreshes. Steps I took are as follows

1) New field added manually to the Table

2) Added new field to the Model DTO and Model ViewModel cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserVM model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            var user = db.User.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(model.Username) && x.Password.Equals(model.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

            if(user != null)
            {
                Session["Id"] = user.Id.ToString();
                Session["Username"] = user.Username.ToString();
                Session["Password"] = user.Password.ToString();
                Session["Firstname"] = user.Firstname.ToString(); //NewField
                Session["RoleName"] = user.RoleName.ToString();

                return RedirectToAction("UserProfile");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username / Password is Invalid");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able fix this by myself. Issue here I noticed was very unique, And i will be glad to explain from start.

I created a table with this info first

Id, Username, Password.

Then created its Action in Controller, and all was set to work.

Later I decided to add new fields to table, say Firstname, Lastname and Email.

Now, here is where the problem came. In Model ViewModel I had created a Model Class as UserVM, So, if I add these new properties to ModelClass with [Required] data annotaion, only then the Login Action does not respond. Action works if I go back and remove [Required] Data annotation.

I did google this to see a solution but no success.

For now Closing this ticket as resolved, but would love to know how can we make the Action run with [Required] data annotation added on the new fields in the Model Class.